# ImportError: cannnot import name 'Imputer' from 'sklearn.preprocessing'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, compilation, auto-sklearn

Trying to import Imputer from sklearn.preprocessing,

```
import pandas as pd
dataset = pd.read_csv('Data.csv')
X = dataset.iloc[:, :-1].values
y = dataset.iloc[:, 3].values

#PART WHERE ERROR OCCURS:-
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
```

Shows "ImportError: cannot import name 'Imputer' from 'sklearn.preprocessing' (/home/codeknight13/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/preprocessing/_*init*_.py)"

Answer (score 135, accepted):

`from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer` was deprecated with `scikit-learn v0.20.4` and removed as of `v0.22.2`. See the [sklean changelog](https://scikit-learn.org/0.20/whats_new.html#id35).

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='mean')
```

`pip install scikit-learn==0.20.4` or `conda install scikit-learn=0.20.4` are not a good options because `scikit-learn==0.20.4` is more than 3 years out of date.